# Can "among" mean "for" in a mathematical context?

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

Suppose the following self made example in the mathematics context:

- The slop is identical for all the cases of n = 1,2,3, ... , 10.

Can I reword this as

> - The slop is identical among all the cases of n = 1,2,3, ... , 10.

Comment: What makes you think you can? Alternately, what do you hope to gain by doing so? The answer below explains that "for" is correct, but maybe this doesn't really give you the information you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example with "for" is how this would normally be phrased. I can see no reason to change to "among". If you did use "among" I would probably understand, but it would seem a little odd, perhaps very odd.